# Xtensa --- dangerous relocation: windowed long call crosses 1GB boundary

Tags: linker-errors, ld, relocation, xtensa

I got the following error during compilation

> (.sram.text+0x1283): dangerous relocation: windowed longcall crosses
>   1GB boundary; return may fail: (*UND*+0xdeadcafe)

in one of the functions.

The architecture is Xtensa and the toolchain used is a GNU toolchain built for Xtensa. This error is inside the function elf_xtensa_do_reloc() in the file elf32-xtensa.c in binutils source code.

Please let me know the cause of this error and any possible solution.

Comment: Formatted error message

Comment: UND+0xdeadcafe is clearly a bogus address, the error is just a consequence of that. The solution involves figuring out why this address was used and fixing that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known caveat of the default Xtensa windowed-register ABI.  Quoting the [Xtensa ISA reference manual](http://0x04.net/~mwk/doc/xtensa.pdf):

> The window increment stored with the return address register in `a4`
>   occupies the two most significant bits of the register, and therefore 
>   those bits must be filled in by the subroutine return. The `RETW` and 
>   `RETW.N` instructions fill in these bits from the two most significant 
>   bits of their own address. This prevents register-window calls from being 
>   used to call a routine in a different 1GB region of the address space.

You have two options to fix this:

1. You can try adjusting the load base address for your code and/or make it smaller (!) until it fits within a 1GB region to fix it.
2. If that doesn't work or isn't an option, you'll have to recompile *everything* running on your Xtensa system with a compiler that supports the alternative CALL0 ABI, which treats the register file as 'flat' and thus avoids the offending windowed call and return instructions.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the same error when developing for ESP32 on PlatformIO, the solution I found was to change the [optimatazion flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) from `-Os` to `-O3`.

```
[env:esp32dev]
build_unflags = -Os
build_flags = -O3
```